# Using regular expressions find all pattern matches of simlar like

Tags: r

parents, grandparents, great grandparents, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@library(tidyvere)
str_extract_all(GivenText, 
+                 "(?ix) ((?: great \\s+)* (?: (?:grand)?) (?: mother|father|brother))")
[[1]]
[1] "mother"                        "father"                        "grandfather"                  
[4] "grandmother"                   "great great grandmother"       "great great great grandfather"
[7] "brother"
```