# How to you perform the regex on the line with multiple same word with distinct meaning?

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have a sentence. My dad, granddad and great great granddad looks alike. How do you create a regex to get dad, granddad , great great grand data value using grep.

I tried using 
`str_extract_all(pattern = "(great)?\s(grand)?(father|mother)", sentence)` but with little success.

Comment: I'd recommend testing regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/imzcrx/1)

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032788/using-regular-expressions-find-all-pattern-matches-of-parents-grandparents-gre/ ?

Comment: Are you and @himal-baral getting homework from the same teacher? stackoverflow.com/questions/62032788/ .  I just answered this question 3 hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
\b(?:(?:great )*granddad|dad)\b
```

R code:

```
sentence <- "My dad, granddad and great great granddad looks alike."
str_extract_all(pattern = "\\b(?:(?:great )*granddad|dad)\\b", sentence)[[1]]

[1] "dad"                  "granddad"             "great great granddad"
```

### Demo

The trick here is to use an alternation, as you were already using, but to place the *more* specific terms first.  The pattern `(?:great )*granddad` will match `great great granddad` first, followed by `great granddad` (which does not actually occur in your sentence), and finally `granddad`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but, It returns the nil value for me. :(

Comment: @NirajHirachan It is working for me in R, I just tested it (and have added the output in R to my answer above).

Comment: The match word boundary was not displaying a result for me. It's working now. Thank you.